# cannot dispatch async function when click button in react

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am developing a component library and want to use the host project's store. I want the component library could access the host project's store. so I use the hook useSelector, useDispath，I found that I could use normal dispatch, but not async dispatch.

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";


export default function AccountInfo({  onAccountClick }) {
  const name = useSelector((state) => state.account.name);
  const balance = useSelector((state) => state.account.balance);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const fetchImage = (url) => async () => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch(url, {
        method: "GET",
      });
      const address = await res.json();
      dispatch({ type: "GET_ACCOUNT_IMAGE", address });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("error");
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <ul>
        <li>name: {name}</li>
        <li>balance: {balance}</li>
      </ul>
      <button className="button" onClick={() => fetchImage("https://aws.random.cat/meow")}>
        Click
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

If I change onClick to :

```
      <button className="button" onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "GET_CONSOLE" })}>
```

It can do the work. But I want it an async function, which didn't work.
How can I solve this?

Comment: You have two functions in fetchImage maybe try just fetchImage = async (url) =>

Comment: cOOL!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Thanks anttud!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: It works but I don't know why! Thanks a million!!!!!!!!!!!!